# Android - passing data of different types

Tags: android, types, android-asynctask

What I am trying to achieve is as follows - I have a java class which calls a URL (passed to it), which returns JSON, which calls a call back from within the calling activity which processes the data.

This allows reusability of the aSyncTask code.

In some cases I needed to pass post data to the URL being called, so I created a new method with allows me to add data

```
HashMap<String, String> mData;        

public void AddDataToPost(HashMap<String, String> data) {
        mData = data;
     }
```

Then I pass this data with my httprequest.

My question is as follows.

I want to be able to pass any type of data in. For example a HashMap.. but i cannot do this because I have head to specify the  bit when I initialized the var.

I could create an addHashMap method, but the same problem arises as the var is initialized as String, String.

How would I go about reusing code whilst allowing the passing of any data form?

THanks

Comment: So you want to be able to pass any type of Object to your Asynctask doInBackground function correct? Possibly more than one Object as an array of Object[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your class to use raw types, e.g.

```
public MyClass<T>{
   ...
}
```

You could then do this:

```
MyClass<Integer> intMyClass = new MyClass<>();

MyClass<String>  strMyClass = new MyClass<>();
```

Note though that you cannot pass primitives so you would have to box integers and so on.

See this tutorial on Java Generics.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class constructor in your Asynctask class, passing it a hashmap of `<String, Object>`, which you can then use anywhere in the Asynctask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private Map<String, Object> myMap;
    private String myString;

    public MyTask(Map<String, Object> myMap, String myString) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
        this.myString = myString;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do stuff with params and myMap
    }
}
```

MainActity.java:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//Add stuff to myMap
new MyTask(myMap, "mystring").execute();
```

Comment: Whether it is in the constructor, or a seperate method is irrelevant - the problem is as to how I can pass in both a string and a hashmap within one method/constructor.. Cheers